# Spring Boot REST - How to implement a search that requires a Java object?

Tags: java, rest, jpa, spring-boot

I have the following JPA models:

**Issue**

```
@Entity
public class Issue {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id;
private String title;
private String text;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="user_id")
private User user;

public Issue() {}

public Issue(String title, String text) {
    this.title = title;
    this.text  = text;
}

public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getText() {
    return text;
}

public void setText(String text) {
    this.text = text;
}

public User getUser() {
    return user;
}

public void setUser(User user) {
    this.user = user;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Issue [id=" + id + ", title=" + title + ", text=" + text + ", user=" + user + "]";
}
}
```

**User**

```
@Entity
public class User {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id;
private String username;
private String firstname;
private String lastname;

public User() {}

public User(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public String getFirstname() {
    return firstname;
}

public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
    this.firstname = firstname;
}

public String getLastname() {
    return lastname;
}

public void setLastname(String lastname) {
    this.lastname = lastname;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "User [id=" + id + ", username=" + username + ", firstname=" + firstname + ", lastname=" + lastname
            + "]";
}
}
```

And an Issue repository that extends `PagingAndSortingRepository` and contains the method `List<Issue> findByUser(User user);` See below:

```
public interface IssueRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Issue,Long> {
    List<Issue> findByUser(User user);
}
```

I'm trying to find a way to navigate these relationships with HTTP calls, namely how do I call `findByUser(User user)` and get all the issues for that user?

Using the following call I can execute that particular query:

`GET http://localhost:8080/issues/search/findByUser`

But I'm unclear what I should be providing as the User? Do I send the id as a query param? Do I construct an object and send that as a query param? Am I just modeling this the wrong way?

I'd like to get back a JSON list containing all the Issues for this particular User.

Thanks in advance for any help or guidance.

Comment: Can you show us your repository??

Comment: Yes, it's posted, now.

Comment: I guess it might be useful to read https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-spring-mvc and http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.8.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the repository to this solved the issue. The key is to do the lookup based on a field of the User, not the User itself.

```
public interface IssueRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Issue,Long> {
    List<Issue> findByUserUsername(@Param("username") String username);
}
```

`GET http://localhost:8080/issues/search/findByUserUsername?username=jerney`

This returns a list of issues.

Answer (score 0):

put another read only column like
@Column(name = "user_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Long userId;
in Issue entity and use findByUserId(Long userId) repo method to find it and pass userId parameter(i.e path varible) to controller to do this using http calls.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple findOne(Long userId) if you need only one record as its probably faster than query by string field